# How do you upload a file to a Milton WebDAV server using curl?

Tags: webdav, milton

When I try to curl using the -T option, I get an empty reply:

```
$ curl --digest -u me:pwd -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -T test.xml http://localhost:8085/
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Anyone know the incantation? The server works fine when connecting to it from the WebDAV client built into MacOSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default curl sends Expect: Continue, but unfortunately java web containers don't play nicely with the Expect header. The simplest answer is to instruct curl not to send that header:

```
curl --digest -u a2 -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -H "Expect:" -T TestPBE-workspace.xml http://localhost:8080/users/a2/files2/
```

The better solution is to make expect:continue work, but from the research i've done it appears that depends on what web container you're using.